# Tesseract JS is having issues finding text in an image

Tags: javascript, electron, ocr, tesseract, tesseract.js

Im trying to use tesseract to pull out numbers in an image into a string. I have an image object `image` passed into this code :

````
Tesseract.recognize(image).then(function(result){         
console.log(result);         
alert(result.text);     })```
````

It process the image, and doesn't find anything.

This is the image:
[image: imagetobesearched]

I tried to pass the image, and a larger image with more pixels. Neither returned with text.